# Ktor websocket server send custom header

Tags: kotlin, websocket, ktor

I have developed a websocket with ktor framework. I wanna send custom header for my websocket to let client catch that header in onOpen callback. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the `ApplicationSendPipeline` to add a header if the body is of the `WebSocketUpgrade` type. Here is an example:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 1234) {
    install(WebSockets)
    sendPipeline.intercept(ApplicationSendPipeline.Transform) { body ->
        if (body is WebSocketUpgrade) {
            call.response.headers.append("custom", "123")
        }
    }

    routing {
        webSocket("/") {
            outgoing.send(Frame.Text("hello"))
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```